# Python function alternative to MATLAB's gpuArray()

Tags: python, performance, matlab, gpu

`MATLAB` has a nice function `gpuArray();` for exploiting the GPU to perform operations at lightning speed (especially if a good graphics card is installed). For neural networks, this is necessary, as input matrices are huge and many complex operations are performed.

In matlab this is simply done by this piece of code,
`G = gpuArray(ones(100, 'uint32'));`

Is there something similar in Python? That is, a library which is open-source and as easy to use as  MATLAB's GPU lib.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you"ll find what you're looking for in PyCUDA:

http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html